# How to query jsonb fields and values containing single quote in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.6

I'm having a Rails app running with PostgreSQL. There is a table called Programs as the following:

```
Program(id: integer, name: string, properties: jsonb)
```

Let say we have a program called "Football Club" where properties are as the following:

```
{
  "properties" => 
    {
      "What's your gender?" => "I'm male.",
      "Is your health good?" => "Yes"
    }
}
```

My query is like this:

```
# this field and value are OK with the query
field = Is your health good?
value = Yes

Program.where("properties ->> '#{field}') = '#{value}'")

# this field and value causes error with the query since they contain quote (')
field = What's your gender?
value = I'm male.

Program.where("properties ->> '#{field}') = '#{value}'")
```

I know that the issue causes by how I interpolate string. Yet, I could not find a solution.
Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Hi, test this: `field.gsub("'", "''")` Replace single quote by 2 quotes

Comment: Hi @Boris! You saved my life. It fixed my issue. Is that mean two single quotes is equivalent to one single quote in jsonb? or the first single quote is how to escape special character in jsonb?

Comment: Hi, yes its equivalent, look here:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences